# Installing the "Perfect" module

Tags: module, plugin

I am trying to try and install this

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/perfect.

does not seem to have the same structure of other modules I have installed. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "Add the Perfect folder to your third_party directory, usually located at /system/expressionengine/third_party unless you moved it." - right from devotee add-on  page

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `perfect` folder inside `/system/expressionengine/third_party`.

(Also: the add-on is [developer-supported via devot:ee's forums](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/perfect/viewforum/2298) - the add-on's developer is far more likely to help you there.)